# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to create a table as follows,

```
create table table1(date1 datetime,date2 datetime);
```

First I tried inserting values as below,

```
insert into table1 values('21-02-2012 6:10:00 PM','01-01-2001 12:00:00 AM');
```

It has given error saying,

> *Cannot convert varchar to datetime*

Then I tried below format as one of the post suggested by our stackoverflow,

```
insert into table1 values(convert(datetime,'21-02-2012 6:10:00 PM',5)
                          ,convert(datetime,'01-01-2001 12:00:00 AM',5));
```

But am still getting the error saying,

> *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string*

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever as you said I have already referred this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957635/sql-query-to-insert-datetime-in-sql-server before asking this question. They asked us to use 'insert table1 (approvaldate)
       values (convert(datetime,'18-06-12 10:34:09 PM',5));' but it doesnt work

Comment: See also:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118880/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string Among other things there is a very helpful query to identify problematic rows

Comment: Just in case someone needs that. Personally I stumbled upon this error when trying to run `SELECT` with `ORDER BY` and `CASE WHEN THEN` inside that `ORDER BY`. When cases included only columns of type `NVARCHAR` it worked fine. But when cases also included columns of type `DATETIME` - I got this conversion error.

Comment: `set DATEFORMAT dmy;` before 1st `insert`

Answer (score 223, accepted):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

So in your specific case - use these strings:

```
insert into table1 values('2012-02-21T18:10:00', '2012-01-01T00:00:00');
```

and you should be fine (note: you need to use the international **24-hour** format rather than 12-hour AM/PM format for this).

**Alternatively**: if you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer, you could also use the `DATETIME2` datatype (instead of plain `DATETIME`) and your current `INSERT` would just work without any problems! :-) `DATETIME2` is a lot better and a lot less picky on conversions - and it's the recommend date/time data types for SQL Server 2008 or newer anyway.

```
SELECT
   CAST('02-21-2012 6:10:00 PM' AS DATETIME2),     -- works just fine
   CAST('01-01-2012 12:00:00 AM' AS DATETIME2)   -- works just fine
```

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

Comment: Just as a note, casting as DATETIME2 also works with 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ' (note 'Z' - Zulu time at the end to denote UTC timestamp). I've got this error while trying to insert '2013-12-16T17:21:26Z' in datetime field.

Just to clarify, ISO 8601 is supported partially. It does not support Zulu time, despite it being mentioned in the documentation.

It's probably some setting I haven't had time to figure out, but in case somebody has the same problem, keep that in mind.

Comment: I can confirm that the 'YYYYMMDD' date format works fine, tried it on SQL Server 2014, as a way to specify a literal date in a WHERE clause. Many tanks to @marc_s

Comment: The DATETIME2 thing worked for me. In my case I was importing a database script from a SQLServer in english to a spanish version of it, so everytime the same error. I simply replaced in the script all the "as DATETIME" ocurrencies to "as DATETIME2" and problem solved.

Answer (score 46):

Sometimes, the conversion in SQL Server fails not because of the Date or Time formats used. It is merely because you are trying to store wrong data that is not acceptable to the system.

Example:

```sql
Create Table MyTable (MyDate);

Insert Into MyTable(MyDate) Values ('2015-02-29');
```

The SQL Server will throw the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The reason for this error is simply there is no such date (Feb-29) in Year (2015).

Comment: _"The reason for this error is simply there is no such date (Feb-29) in Year (2015)"_   This was exactly the reason I was getting this error.  This answer takes into account the most common cause of this error, that the other answers did not.

Comment: I imported data from an Excel sheet where the null values actually had "NULL" in the cell. This got set as a string "Null" in the DB table, so was trying to convert the string "Null" to a datetime.  Should have emptied out the "NULL" cells in Excel. I'm an idiot :/

Comment: This was my issue.  2023-09-31 doesn't exist...

Answer (score 22):

Simple answer - 5 is Italian "yy" and 105 is Italian "yyyy". Therefore:

```
SELECT convert(datetime,'21-02-12 6:10:00 PM',5)
```

will work correctly, but

```
SELECT convert(datetime,'21-02-12 6:10:00 PM',105)
```

will give error.

Likewise,

```
SELECT convert(datetime,'21-02-2012 6:10:00 PM',5)
```

will give error, where as

```
SELECT convert(datetime,'21-02-2012 6:10:00 PM',105)
```

will work.

Answer (score 13):

Whenever possible **one should avoid culture specific date/time literals**.

There are some *secure* formats to provide a date/time as literal:

All examples for `2016-09-15 17:30:00`

#### ODBC (my favourite, as it is handled as the *real* type immediately)

- `{ts'2016-09-15 17:30:00'}` --Time Stamp
- `{d'2016-09-15'}`           --Date only
- `{t'17:30:00'}`             --Time only

#### ISO8601 (the best for *everywhere*)

- `'2016-09-15T17:30:00'` --be aware of the `T` in the middle!

#### Unseperated (tiny risk to get misinterpreted as number)

- `'20160915'`              --only for *pure* date

#### Good to keep in mind: Invalid dates tend to show up with *strange errors*

- There is no 31st of June or 30th of February...

#### One more reason for strange conversion errors: Order of execution!

SQL-Server is well know to do things in an order of execution one might not have expected. Your written statement looks like the conversion is done **before** some type related action takes place, but the engine decides - why ever - to do the conversion in a later step.

Here is a great article explaining this with examples: [Rusano.com: "t-sql-functions-do-no-imply-a-certain-order-of-execution"](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/10/t-sql-functions-do-no-imply-a-certain-order-of-execution/) and here is [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6989522/5089204).

Comment: The "Good to keep in mind" part was exactly what I needed to find my error. +1 just for that.

Answer (score 10):

Just update the date format  as like bellow

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss
```

It solves the problem for me and it works fine

Comment: Please read the other answers already provided. This format works for you only because of your session `DATEFORMAT` setting.  Verify this by running `SET DATEFORMAT MDY;SELECT CAST('2017-08-07 00:00:00' AS datetime);
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;SELECT CAST('2017-08-07 00:00:00' AS datetime);`. It will work reliably if you add a `T` separator (`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`).

Comment: Thanks very much yes you are right it solves my problem and I read the other answers given here

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(date, yourDate ,104)
```

Answer (score 7):

This error is also displayed when the date doesn't exist (e.g., the date `'09-31-2021'` doesn't exist, because September has a length of 30 days).

Comment: This was actually my problem. The user was entering February 30

Answer (score 5):

the best way is this code

```
"select * from [table_1] where date between convert(date,'" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "',105) and convert(date,'" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "',105)"
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how to easily convert from an ISO string to a SQL-Server `datetime`:

```
INSERT INTO time_data (ImportateDateTime) VALUES (CAST(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,'2019-09-13 22:06:26.527000') AS datetime))
```

Source https://www.sqlservercurry.com/2010/04/convert-character-string-iso-date-to.html

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when trying to concatenate `getdate()` into a string that I was inserting into an nvarchar field.

I did some casting to get around it:

```
 INSERT INTO [SYSTEM_TABLE] ([SYSTEM_PROP_TAG],[SYSTEM_PROP_VAL]) VALUES 
   (
    'EMAIL_HEADER',
    '<h2>111 Any St.<br />Anywhere, ST 11111</h2><br />' + 
        CAST(CAST(getdate() AS datetime2) AS nvarchar) + 
    '<br /><br /><br />'
   )
```

That's a sanitized example.  The key portion of that is:

`...' + CAST(CAST(getdate() AS datetime2) AS nvarchar) + '...`

Casted the date as `datetime2`, then as `nvarchar` to concatenate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
convert(datetime2,((SUBSTRING( ISNULL(S2.FechaReal,e.ETA),7,4)+'-'+ SUBSTRING( ISNULL(S2.FechaReal,e.ETA),4,2)+'-'+ SUBSTRING( ISNULL(S2.FechaReal,e.ETA),1,2) + ' 12:00:00.127')))  as fecha,
```

Comment: If you use backticks, rather than initial spaces, you'll get word-wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

The datetime format actually that runs on sql server is

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss
```

Comment: No, this is not true (besides the mismatch of  `m` and `M`). Read Dan Guzman's comment to Pronab Roy's answer. And read the other answers here...

Answer (score 2):

Please Try this.

SQL Server expects dates in MM/DD/YYYY format,If English is set as your default language.Here am saving datepicker value to sql2008 database.My field type is datetime in database.dpdob is my datepicker name.

```
           Dim test = dpdob.Text.Replace("-", "/")
           Dim parts As String() = test.Split(New Char() {"/"c})
           Dim firstPart As String = parts(0)
           Dim thirdPart As String = parts(2)
           Dim secondPart As String = parts(1)
           Dim test1 = secondPart + "/" + firstPart + "/" + thirdPart
           Dim dob = test1
```

Now use dob in your insert query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
select (Convert(Date, '2018-04-01'))
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable]
           ([ValidFrom]
           ,[ValidTo])
       VALUES
           ('2020-01-27 14:54:11.000'
           ,'2023-01-27 14:52:50.000')
```

Answer (score 1):

For me with EF Core, I needed to use OnModelCreating

For my Job Table, CreatedOn smalldatetime field.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().Property(x => x.CreatedOn).HasColumnType("datetime")
```

Answer (score 0):

set Culture to english from web.config file

```
  <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

for example if you set the culture to arabic the thime will be

‏22‏/09‏/2017‏ 02:16:57 ص

and you get the error:Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime

Answer (score 0):

While writing your SQL insert query, write your date in single quotes and use forward slash in date format (DD/MM/YYYY)
like this:

```sql
insert into table_name (Emp_Id, Name, **DOB**) values
(01, 'Suresh Kumawat', **'22/03/2015'**);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error message "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." showed up while trying to insert 'null' (string) into a nullable datetime column. Changing this to null (removing single quotes) fixed the problem.

Example:

```
declare @DateTable table(dateColumn datetime null)
insert into @DateTable (dateColumn)
values ('null')--Implicit conversion does not convert 'null' to a null.
--Output: Error message: Conversion failed when converting date and/or 
time from character string.

insert into @DateTable (dateColumn)
values (null)
--Output: null inserted into table
```

Answer (score -1):

##### if you use dotnet6 you can validate  like this.

```
someDate = Util.SystemDate.GetValidatedDateTime(someDate);
```

and then you can use in SQL.