# Error occured while trying to insert in a table

Tags: mysql, type-conversion, date-conversion

I am getting the error
`Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1`
`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

on this INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO COMMITTE_MEMBERS(PLAYERNO, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE, POSITION)
VALUES 
  (2, '1990-01-01', '1992-12-31', 'CHAIRMAN'),
  (2, '1994-01-01', 'NULL', 'MEMBER'),
  (6, '1992-01-01', '1994-12-31', 'SECRETARY'),
  (6, '1991-01-01', '1992-12-31', 'MEMBER'),
  (6, '1990-01-01', '1993-12-31', 'TREASURER'),
  (6, '1993-01-01', 'NULL', 'CHAIRMAN'),
  (8, '1994-01-01', '1994-12-31', 'TREASURER'),
  (8, '1991-01-01', '1993-12-31', 'SECRETARY'),
  (8, '1990-01-01', '1991-12-31', 'MEMBER'),
  (8, '1992-01-01', 'NULL', 'MEMBER'),
  (27, '1990-01-01', '1990-12-31', 'MEMBER'),
  (27, '1992-01-01', '1994-12-31', 'TREASURER'),
  (27, '1991-01-01', '1992-12-31', 'TREASURER'),
  (57, '1993-01-01', '1993-12-31', 'SECRETARY'),
  (95, '1994-01-01', 'NULL', 'TREASURER'),
  (112, '1992-01-01', '1992-12-31', 'MEMBER'),
  (112, '1994-01-01', 'NULL', 'SECRETARY')
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i

Comment: Try to run this from mysql command line console, and show us real MySQL error message. ...but, your query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try **STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y')**
on your datecolumn.

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO COMMITTE_MEMBERS(PLAYERNO, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE, POSITION)
VALUES 
  (2, STR_TO_DATE('1990-01-01', '%m/%d/%Y'), '1992-12-31', 'CHAIRMAN')
```

Comment: Thanks if you do not mind can you explain more on your answer and why please. I am still new in this field. Thanks

Comment: Thanks if you do not mind can you explain more on your answer and why please. I am still new in this field. Thanks

Comment: I am converting the varchar to proper date format before inserting