# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, date-conversion

I have below SQL.

```
 UPDATE  student_queues
 SET  Deleted=0,  
      last_accessed_by='raja', 
      last_accessed_on=CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),'23-07-2014 09:37:00',113)
 WHERE std_id IN ('2144-384-11564') 
   AND reject_details='REJECT'
```

when I ran the above SQL the below exception has been throwed.

`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: `select CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),'23-07-2014 09:37:00',113)` works on my machine, what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: is `last_accessed_by` a datetime column?

Comment: @Tanner The last accessed_by column is VARCHAR(50) and Last_accessed_on is DATETIME2

Comment: sorry I meant to ask about `last_accessed_on`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're trying to insert in to `last_accessed_on`, which is a `DateTime2`, then your issue is with the fact that you are converting it to a `varchar` in a format that SQL doesn't understand.

If you modify your code to this, it should work, note the format of your date has been changed to: **YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss**:

```
UPDATE  student_queues 
SET  Deleted=0, 
     last_accessed_by='raja', 
     last_accessed_on=CONVERT(datetime2,'2014-07-23 09:37:00')
WHERE std_id IN ('2144-384-11564') AND reject_details='REJECT'
```

Or if you want to use `CAST`, replace with:

```
CAST('2014-07-23 09:37:00.000' AS datetime2)
```

This is using the [SQL ISO Date Format](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977(v=sql.90).aspx).

Comment: Thank you somuch .It works fine with the date format change as YYYY-MM-DD . Also I didnt change the type from VARCHAR to datetime2.Its working fine with the VARCHAR(24)

Comment: The issue is simply with your choice of date format and SQL's inability to understand it as a datetime. Updating to the ISO format allows SQL to understand it hence it worked with the varchar.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like last_accessed_on, is a date time, and you are converting '23-07-2014 09:37:00' to a varchar. This would not work, and give you conversion errors. Try

```
last_accessed_on= convert(datetime,'23-07-2014 09:37:00', 103)
```

I think you can avoid the cast though, and update with **'23-07-2014 09:37:00'**. It should work given that the format is correct.

Your query is not going to work because in **last_accessed_on** (which is **DateTime2** type), you are trying to pass a **Varchar** value.

You query would be

```
UPDATE  student_queues SET  Deleted=0 ,  last_accessed_by='raja', last_accessed_on=convert(datetime,'23-07-2014 09:37:00', 103)  
 WHERE std_id IN ('2144-384-11564') AND reject_details='REJECT'
```

Comment: Can you pls explain .I am getting confused

Comment: Did the query work, when using cast('23-07-2014 09:37:00' as datetime)? If yes, last_accessed_on is of type DateTime, and in order for an update to work - you cannot pass a varchar type, into a field with another type such as datetime.

Comment: the last_accessed_on field is DATETIME2 Nullable field

Comment: Exactly, so you cannot pass a varchar value into the date time field. My answer above should have worked for you - correct?

Comment: Updated my answer as well.

Comment: how to apply this cast function in the above query .Can you please guide me.Because I want to convert the value in 113 or 120 format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57820/discussion-between-mez-and-user3669712).

Comment: @Mez Have you actually tried this: `select cast('23-07-2014 09:37:00' as datetime)`, as it doesn't work in SQL Server as it doesn't understand the format it's being passed in, hence my use of the ISO format in my answer.

Comment: This works convert(datetime,'23-07-2014 09:37:00', 103)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME

SET @FromDate =  'Jan 10 2016 12:00AM'

DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME
SET @ToDate = 'Jan 10 2017 12:00AM'

DECLARE @Dynamic_Qry nvarchar(Max) =''

SET @Dynamic_Qry='SELECT

(CONVERT(DATETIME,(SELECT 
     CASE WHEN (  ''IssueDate''   =''IssueDate'') THEN 
               EMP_DOCUMENT.ISSUE_DATE 
          WHEN (''IssueDate'' =''ExpiryDate'' ) THEN       
               EMP_DOCUMENT.EXPIRY_DATE ELSE EMP_DOCUMENT.APPROVED_ON END   
          CHEKDATE ), 101)  

)FROM CR.EMP_DOCUMENT  as EMP_DOCUMENT WHERE 1=1 

AND  (
      CONVERT(DATETIME,(SELECT 
        CASE WHEN (  ''IssueDate''   =''IssueDate'') THEN
                 EMP_DOCUMENT.ISSUE_DATE 
             WHEN (''IssueDate'' =''ExpiryDate'' ) THEN EMP_DOCUMENT.EXPIRY_DATE 
             ELSE EMP_DOCUMENT.APPROVED_ON END 
             CHEKDATE ), 101)  
) BETWEEN  '''+ CONVERT(CHAR(10), @FromDate, 126) +'''  AND '''+CONVERT(CHAR(10),  @ToDate , 126
)
+'''  
'

print @Dynamic_Qry

EXEC(@Dynamic_Qry)
```