# Excel: Query SQL table with date parameter from cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an ODBC connection, which simply queries a SQL table:

```
 SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE myDate = ?
```

If I run the query in MS Query, it prompts for a date and I can just enter `4/2/2015` and it returns `4/2/2015` data perfectly

I have the parameter set to read from cell (B1):

```
=WorkSheetName!$B$1
```

When I switch back to Excel and put `4/2/2015` in `B1` and then refresh - it gives me a conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error.

I tried editing my query to `WHERE CONVERT(Varchar(10),myDate,101) = ?` but had no luck.  Not sure why I am getting this, seems like it should be so simple.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the feedback I was getting - but it turned out to be something very simple on my part that I was overlooking.  The actual cell I was keeping my date was formatted as a date, and giving a conversion error.  Once I formatted it to a text cell, it returned the data properly for the given date.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The filter part must be padded with `#` while trying to use `Date` as a filter.

It should be like

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE myDate = #4/2/2015#
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but where shoudl the # #s go?  If I put them in my command text (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE myDate= #?# I get a slew of errors (invalid column name '#@P1#' , Statement(s) could not be prepared / The following data range failed to refresh" etc...

Comment: Hi Saagar I have no VBA code.  I tried putting a form button in to worksheets.refreshall at one point but that didnt work so I got rid of it.  Its all being done through the connection definition tabs

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907360/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

Converting the "myDate" column to "Smalldatetime" format should work for you.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE Cast(myDate as smalldatetime) = ?
```

Thanks