# MSSQL Server 2008 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string Error

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pdo

I am currently receiving the MSSQL Server 2008 error: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

I've checked the following threads but am still having no lucks:

[Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i)
[Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in SQL SERVER 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907360/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-in-sql)

Here is the query (I'm using PHP's PDO SQLSRV):

```
SELECT ISNULL(MYDATE,'None') AS MYDATE, 
ISNULL(CAST(rnm AS NVARCHAR(50)),'None') AS Rnm, 
DATENAME(dw, MYDATE) as nameOfDay, 
FROM tab1
INNER JOIN rnm ON (tab1.rte = rnm.rte)
WHERE DATEDIFF(S, '1970-01-01', MYDATE) >= :startDate
AND DATEDIFF(S, '1970-01-01', MYDATE) <= :endDate
GROUP BY MYDATE, CAST(rnm AS NVARCHAR(50)) WITH ROLLUP
```

The MYDATE field is of the type `datetime` in MSSQL.  I have tried casting each of the MYDATE variables and the `1970-01-01` all as datetime, but I still receive the error.

The "rnm" is cast as VARCHAR because it's an old DB using the "text" type still, unfortunately.

Thanks.

---update:

```
$startDate = strtotime($_GET['startDate'] . " 00:00:00");
$endDate = strtotime($_GET['endDate'] . " 23:59:59");
```

The above is then bound to the prepared variable via `bindParam()`.

Comment: have you tried '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' instead of '1970-01-01'?

Comment: what is ;startDate and :endDate ? date time ? Note that datedfif() returns an integer

Comment: And maybe this is the problem: `ISNULL(MYDATE,'None') AS MYDATE`. Maybe the error happens on trying to convert 'None' to a date. I am not sure if it uses MYDATE always from db or from your local alias.

Comment: Added some additional in the question for you @Squirrel.   steven, hmmm, that could be the problem - how can I force MSSQL to take the DB values again if it was trying to do that?

Comment: steven hit the nail. The issue is the ISNULL(MYDATE, 'None'), change to ISNULL ( convert (varchar(10), MYDATE), 'None') and also in the GROUP BY clause also

Comment: or remove the ISNULL () on MYDATE. let it return NULL and handle that in your front end.

Comment: @Squirrel well that did stop the error, but I have no data being returned after fetch, so I have bigger problems on my hand =).  Thanks.

Comment: datediff() returns integer. You are comparing integer with date. Since : startDate and endDate are just datetime, why not juse WHERE MYDATE >= startDate

Comment: @Squirrel The strtotime produces an integer as well as a unix timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by MYDATE which is datetime instead of IsNull(MYDATE, 'None') which is varchar and sometimes stores 'None' as a value.
All those DATEDIFFs and conversions inside WHERE clause will lead to performance issues. Try to remove DATEDIFFs and pass startdate/enddate in datetime format.