# getting date conversion error while converting datetimepicker value to date in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime

I am getting "conversion failed when converting date and or time from character string".I have a function which for converting datetimpicker value to specific date format. and I am calling that in a sql query . please correct me where i am wrong.this is my function for converting datetimepicker value to my specific format:

```
Public Function convertDateTimePickerToDate(ByVal Datevalue As DateTimePicker) As Date

    Dim convertedDate As Date
    Dim format = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    Dim dateString As String = Datevalue.Value.ToString(format)
    convertedDate = Date.ParseExact(dateString, format, Nothing)
    Return convertedDate

End Function
```

and in my sql query i am calling it as:-

sql = "INSERT INTO SIM_SALES VALUES('" & txt_simNO.Text & "','" &txt_simMSISDN.Text & "','" & txt_simCustName.Text & "','" & convertDateTimePickerToDate(dtp_simSaleDate) & "')"

please correct me where I am wrong. or is there any other suggestions through which i can implement the same logic. thanks in advance

Comment: There's a similar open topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i

Answer (score 0):

That format string only applies while it is a string. When you convert it back to a date structure that information is lost. When the date is re-converted back to a string when you append it to your sql string it uses the current culture's default format which looks like it might be `dd/MM/yyyy` for you.
SQL Server expects `MM/dd/yyyy` if doing a blind string to date conversion.

However using SQL parameters will solve the two issues you have here, the first being the wrong date serialization format and the second is a SQL injection vulnerability. A user could enter sql commands into those textboxes which would get executed after joining them together.

Look into using `command.Parameters.AddWithValue()` if you are using ado.net and pass the date structure in as is.