# Insert DateTime into SQL DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to insert a `DateTime` into my SQL Server table column of type `DateTime2(7)` using the INSERT INTO syntax.

The error I receive is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion failed when converting date and/or
>   time from character string.

I initialize the `DateTime` variable with:

```
DateTime TaskCreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

and use it here:

```
insertTaskCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskCreatedDate", TaskCreatedDate);
```

Any thoughts?

**Update:**

I have tried:

```
insertTaskCmd.Parameters.Add("@TaskCreatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = TaskCreatedDate;
```

with the same error being produced.

Full query:

```
            string insertTask = String.Format("INSERT INTO [Tasks] VALUES (@TaskNumber, '@TaskCreatedDate', '', '', '', @Status, '3', '')");
            SqlCommand insertTaskCmd = new SqlCommand(insertTask, conn);
            insertTaskCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskNumber", newTaskNumbers[i]);

            insertTaskCmd.Parameters.Add("@TaskCreatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = TaskCreatedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            insertTaskCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", 0); // 0 is Active
            insertTaskCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i)

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: a handy replacement for `AddWithValue` is  `Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@paramName", SqlDbType.WhatEver, columnSize) { Value = valueVariable };`. When you always specify the same size for character columns, you will produce only one execution plan. When you leave it out, you end with one plan for each parameter value length combination you are using in the query.

Comment: I'm extremely glad I've read that, but in this case, it didn't solve the issue.  Thanks

Comment: Great tip by @eFloh. Could you maybe also specify what you are doing? Are you called a Stored Procedure or using default INSERT INTO syntax? Either way, could you perhaps include the query you are using?

Comment: you should tell us what the actual datatype of the `TaskCreatedDate` is it a DateTime or a TimeStamp

Comment: And if it's not a Datetime, try making it one.

Comment: also is this a typo `insertTaskCmd.Parameters.Add("@TaskCreatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value` the `DateTime2`...?? @Lighty please show what the stored proc or query looks like as well as the Table Schema in regards to the dataype of the field. it will help in eliminating any and all guess work from us

Comment: I tried it with DateTime and DateTime2, both are valid SQL types

Comment: @jean the easiest thing to do is to not change it to a varchar(30) the simplest thing to do for the OP is to tell us what the actual datatype is for that column as well as the query

Comment: first problem I see is in the query.. why are you not defining the exact fields that you want to insert into.. try changing the query and I bet it will work.. also if you are going to post code..please show how all relevant values in regards to your issue are used, populated and or defined `newTaskNumbers` ...?? refactor your query to use `Parameterized query` wrap all the Sql objects around a using. as well, wrap all Executing attempts around a `try{}catch{}` you are assuming that your query will always run without failure

Comment: Is there a **trigger** on that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Note around the @TaskCreatedDate there are single quotation marks (').  Remove these and it's solved.

Comment: you need to remove all quoted text and start using / learning how to use parameters.. as well as the debugger.. respectfully speaking

Comment: @MethodMan: That seems uncalled for. The OP does use parameters. Some of the inserted values happen to be constants, hence the need to use quotes.

Comment: @AndriyM perhaps you missed this part in the OP's original question `'@TaskCreatedDate'`

Answer (score 4):

I think your insert query is just wrong - you have the `@TaskCreatedDate` in single quotes - that shouldn't be .....

Try this:

```
string insertTask = "INSERT INTO [Tasks] VALUES (@TaskNumber, @TaskCreatedDate, '', '', '', @Status, '3', '')";

SqlCommand insertTaskCmd = new SqlCommand(insertTask, conn);
insertTaskCmd.Parameters.Add("@TaskNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  newTaskNumbers[i];
insertTaskCmd.Parameters.Add("@TaskCreatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = TaskCreatedDate;
insertTaskCmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0; // 0 is Active

insertTaskCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note: I would also recommend to [**always**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) explicitly specify the columns you want to insert into:

```
string insertTask = @"INSERT INTO [Tasks](TaskNumber, TaskCreatedDate, .., .., .., Status, .. ..)
                      VALUES (@TaskNumber, @TaskCreatedDate, '', '', '', @Status, '3', '')");
```