# Cannot convert from specific string to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I know there are many questions of this kind, and I have already seen another questions as this one: [Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i)

But the main thing is that I cannot convert a specific string to datetime using any format using SQL Server. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
DECLARE @1 AS VARCHAR(500)
SET @1 = '18/03/2015 08:07:25 a.m.'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @1, 131)
```

This is not working, even if i tried with several formats as specified here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

For what I've tried it just works with 131 format if the string containing the datetime is on 24 hour format, like this:

```
DECLARE @1 AS VARCHAR(500)
SET @1 = '18/03/2015 08:07:25'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @1, 131)
```

Does anyone know how can I do to convert that string to datetime as I need?.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: what kind of duplicate? I'm talking of SQL server, not PYTHON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying the @1 to be in the correct format, that's all

```
DECLARE @1 AS VARCHAR(500)
SET @1 = '18/03/2015 08:07:25 am'
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @1,103)
```

Please see this webpage for more on formatting

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: That query is returning '2576-10-11 08:07:25.000'. I will check that now