# I want to update field with "Datetime" datatype in table of my database from DateTimePicker object in C#

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

Note: Don't care with Connection becuse the connection work.
Field in database is `DateTime`

```
DateTime dtc = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);

cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE LAB_TESTING set Lab_Nam='" + lab_id + "',Rslt_lb='" + 
                     textBox1.Text + "',Tst_Dat='" + dtc + "' Where Lab_ID='" + 
                     bindex + "'", con);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("You Update recored successfully", "delete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
con.Close();
readdatagrid1();
```

after Run program , I got Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string concatenation to build your queries ([SQL injection alert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), also [read this](http://xkcd.com/327/)!). Use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx). As for your problem: format the date as `yyyy-MM-dd` ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) and it'll work.

If you'd have used parameterized queries correctly you could've just passed in the DateTime as-is and the driver would've ensured the value would get passed correctly to SQL regardless the "format" / locale setting / whatever since the value would be passed as a DateTime instead of a string. Something like this:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE LAB_TESTING set Lab_Nam = @labnam,
                            Rslt_lb = @result, Tst_Dat = @tstdat
                            Where Lab_ID = @id", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@labnam", lab_id );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tstdat", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", bindex);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Other than that I also recommend to wrap the `con` and `cmd` in a `using() { ... }` statement so that you can be sure this stuff gets disposed properly and that you give your variables and fieldnames decent names and use a consistent naming scheme.

Now repeat after me:

- *I will never, ever, run queries again that have been string-concatenated together anymore!*
- *From now on I will use parameterized queries*
- > ***If*** I need to run string-concatenated queries ever again I will make sure all values are **escaped** properly

Repeat the above aloud, at least 50 times.

Comment: reject the "AddWithValue" as it got red under line.

Comment: `got red under line`... again: tell us the exact error. "Red line" could be anything. Your errors window (or hovering your mouse over the underlined code) will show the actual error. Also please note that I wrote the above code as an **example**. You may have to change it to your needs or... I dunno... maybe refer to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) for a change?

Comment: the error is "doesn't definition for AddWithValue "

Comment: might I didn't explain good ,because i am just start with C# and I am facing the datetime problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTime dtc = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

or else

you can also do this

```
DateTime dtc = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text)
```

If you are getting this error with your SQL code than have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14119145/3796048)

Comment: I used both codes you proposed above but didn't work, also got this message "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Letz try this `DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimePicker1.Text)`

Comment: BTW you are getting this error on `DateTime dtc = Convert.ToDateTime(...)` line or somewhere else

Comment: Don't use a locale specific format; most of the world uses dd-MM-yyyy. [ISO 8601](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32391926/215042) will always work.

Comment: also doesnt work this  DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimePicker1.Text) also i have this code DateTime dtc = Convert.ToDateTime(...) orginally in my code and doesnt work.

Comment: i have changed format of datetimepicker in custom format dd-MM-yyyy before posted my problem here.

Comment: Read the link. Don't use dd-MM-yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy... Use `yyyy-mm-dd` (e.g. ISO 8601) if you  REALLY have to. But better use [parameterized query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32391926/215042).

Comment: `also dosnt work` ... well that clarifies a lot. At least give us the exact error. I think you need to write `MM` (months) instead of `mm` (minutes); I wrote that wrong. Also: changing the format of your datetime picker doesn't change a thing if you're trying to write it's `value` to your database. The format is for *display* purposed only; the `value` is still a DateTime value. You need to learn the difference between representation and actual value. Again: refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32391926/215042) to stay away from this hell alltogether...

Comment: Why convert a date to a string and then back to a date?  That makes no sense.  Just pass `dateTimePicker1.Value.Date` to the query using a parameter.  Don't convert to string _at all_!

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
    var date = (DateTime)dateTimePicker1.SelectedDate.Value;
```

Comment: dosent work because there is red line under (Date) and under SelectedDate .

Comment: I have changed (Date) to (DateTime) so try that.