# How to fix error "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string" in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel-4, sql-server-2012

The error that I found at the log is the one below.

> 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion
>   failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS aggregate 
FROM [mytable] 
WHERE [mytable].[deleted_at] IS NULL 
    AND [created_at] BETWEEN '2015-09-30T00:00:00' AND '2015-09-30T23:59:59' 
    AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [mytable_translation] 
         WHERE [mytable_translation].[item_id] = [mytable].[id]) >= 1)
```

> )' 
>   in
>   wwwroot\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:625

On the database, the DataType is `datetime` and is **not null**

Based on [marc_s's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14119145/662581) I tried to change the format that I'm sending to the database. So I tried without the `T` on `and [created_at] between '2015-09-30 00:00:00' and '2015-09-30 23:59:59'`.

In my local, I'm using mysql, and the code works just fine. If I test the query above on the SQL Server client, both (with and without the `T`) works too.

---

How can I fix this problem without create any changes on the database itself?

The PHP/Laravel code:

```
$items = $items->whereBetween($key, ["'".$value_aux."T00:00:00'", "'".$value_aux."T23:59:59'"]);
```

Comment: Try: `{ts'1900-01-01 00:00:00'}` this format, like `between {ts '2015-09-30 00:00:00'} and ...`

Comment: Sorry @lad2025 I don't know how I could implement this format (if you are talking about the YYYY-DD-MM is already being at use as the example from above)

Comment: How `2015-09-30` is YYYY-MM-DD? Try also `SET DATEFORMAT YMD`

Comment: @lad2025 (2015 == YYYY); (09 == MM); (30 == DD); last day of September of 2015

Comment: I talk about your `f you are talking about the YYYY-DD-MM is already being at use as the example from above)`

Comment: @lad2025 I just said that in the piece of code `AND [created_at] BETWEEN '2015-09-30T00:00:00' AND '2015-09-30T23:59:59'` I'm using the format **YYYY-DD-MM** as you can see. And asked if it's not that what you suggested. If not, then how could I implement your suggestion, so I can bring the result?

Comment: Before query  place `SET DATEFORMAT YMD;  your query;` And you will change for session dateformat.

Comment: @lad2025 got it to work. based on the point of your comments. Thanks. I changed in the code part the format that I was passing. (just added to a variable before passing to the query. This way, I let the database decide the format that he wants)

Comment: Great to hear it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @lad2025 help, I got it to work.

Based on the point of his comments on my question, I changed in the code part (Laravel/PHP in this case) the format that I was passing. (In reality, I "removed" the format it self, and just added fields to a variable before passing to the query. This way, I let the database decide the format that he wants)

Instead of

```
$itens = $itens->whereBetween($key, ["'".$value_aux."T00:00:00'", "'".$value_aux."T23:59:59'"]);
```

I changed the code to this:

```
$sta = $value_aux."T00:00:00";
$end = $value_aux."T23:59:59";
$itens = $itens->whereBetween($key, [$sta, $end]);
```