# Incorrect SQL 'BETWEEN' syntax

Tags: sql

I'm trying to run a simple query.

```
  SELECT power_output.*
  FROM power_output
  WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN '{StartDate}'
  AND t_stamp '{EndDate}'
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'Mon Jan 11 00:00:00 EST 2016'
```

I'd like it to return 'mm/dd/yyyy'

Comment: Remove the second `t_stamp`.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is:

```
 SELECT power_output.*
 FROM power_output
 WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN '{StartDate}' AND '{EndDate}'
```

Column is only declared once see [BETWEEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I removed the second t_stamp and the error I get now is: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the column after the `between x and x`.

This will work:

```
 SELECT power_output.*
  FROM power_output
  WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN '{StartDate}' AND '{EndDate}'
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. I removed the second t_stamp and the error I get now is: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i