# SQL Server - Calculate Age from date of birth in Varchar

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures

Using **SQL Server 2008 R2**

I have a database of my friend's project. He used varchar to store date of birth of members because he was getting errors parsing entries to date. I want to show the age using a procedure code.

the format of date stored in `mm/dd/yyyy` where **today's date is stored as 3/4/2016** . I wanted to use DATEDIFF function but it is not a good option with varchar.

Comment: You have to convert the varchar to a datetime first

Comment: Are you getting any error. Add the query through which you parsed the varchar data

Comment: some  good reads:https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14119145/2975396

Answer (score 0):

```
Create procedure spCalculateAge
@dob varchar(10)
as
Begin
Select DATEDIFF(year,Convert(date,@dob),getdate()) as Age
End
```

I used this and it worked. Before it was giving conversion error but opening and closing SQL Server caused it to work.