# Column of Date type and inserting value into it

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

Hi I created a table in which one column is of `date` type and also works as **PK**. I tried to insert value `2009-01-07` into this column and had this error. Isn't Date default format `yyyy-mm-dd`? I don't understand this.

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO Table_Name
Values ('2009-01-07', other column values)
```

Comment: Something else is going on, because `'2009-01-07'` can be inserted as a date. Try creating an entirely new (table and/or) column as a date and see if you can insert into that column. It sounds to me as if you might have a trigger or check constraint calling a function or some language settings - or something similar - on the table which fails working on the value. Or that it's one of the `other column values` that fails of course.

Comment: Can you write another _INSERT_ query calling columns' name explicitly? For example: `INSERT INTO Table_Name (Date_PK, ...) VALUES ('2009-01-07', ...)`. Just want to make sure which column raises the exception. `2009-01-07` should be OK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i)

Comment: Execute Select GETDATE(), Refer the output of it and change your date format accordingly

Comment: Make sure you list the target column _names_: `insert into table_name (col1, col2, ...) values (...)` - probably the columns in the table are not in the same order as they appear in your `values` list

Answer (score 0):

Your value `'2009-01-07'` should be converted.

Date literals are always a deep source of troubles... Best was, to use either

- Unseparated: 20090107
- ODBC       : {d'2009-01-07'}
- ISO8601    : 2009-01-07T00:00:00

But your format is *short ISO 8601* and should work...

Some possible reasons:

- Other values in your `VALUES` list
- a trigger
- a constraint
- As *a_horse_with_no_name* stated in comment: Without a column list after `INSERT INTO Table(col1, col2, ...)` There is a great risk to state your values in a different order thus pairing values with the wrong columns...
- Invalid (but *good looking*) dates such as `2016-06-31`

Or a - well known - issue with SQL-Server. Sometimes the order of execution is absolutely not the way one expected it. There are several issues with conversion errors...

What you can try

- Use ODBC format (which is treated as `DATETIME` immediately)
- DECLARE a variable with this value and put it in place

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the prompt replies. I read and tried all of them and found out why.

1. '2009-01-07' can be inserted into a Column with "Date" as data type if no CONSTRAINT has issue with that;
2. my problem was caused by a CHECK constraint on that column. 
      Originally I set CONSTRAINT as
      Column_Name = 'Wednesday' 
      After I modified it to 
      DATEName(dw,[Column_Name]) = 'Wednesday' 
      the inserting began to work.

Thanks again.