# Why date is not taking 13/09/2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am checking condition for `12/09/2016` to  `13/09/2016` but it is not showing me data for `13/09/2016` and giving error

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
   b.mkey ,  a.N_UserMkey, cuser_id,isnull(a.N_UserMkey,cuser_id) aa,
   ISNULL(b.first_name + ' ', '')  
   + ISNULL(b.last_name, '') NAME, convert(varchar,a.U_datetime,103) Action_Date
  FROM      inward_doc_tracking_trl a  
   INNER JOIN user_mst b ON isnull(a.N_UserMkey,cuser_id) = b.mkey  
  WHERE 
  convert(datetime,a.U_datetime,103) 
    BETWEEN convert(varchar,'12/09/2016',103)
  AND convert(varchar,'13/09/2016',103)
   and b.mkey=2357
```

Comment: Format `MM/DD/YYYY`?

Comment: @jarlh: no, I want in `dd/MM/yyy` format. I have used 103 for that

Comment: I'm just guessing that, due the language of the system, it's taking the data with format: "month/day/year". Try `2016-09-13`

Comment: @nad that would be the format AFTER conver function ends. But, convert function recieves a string, ¿Which format is considered to parse that string INSIDE convert function?. Convert function analices the string taking the datetime-format default on the system. So it's perfectly possible that convert function, parse `13` as month as @jarlh said

Comment: @nad The `style` attribute in `CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)` only applies for date or time data type. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it seems that you are cummulating several mistakes here:

- Do not check for date ranges with `BETWEEN`. This is very erronous, due to the time-portion of a datetime. Often forgotten... You might [read this great blog by Aaron Betrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- Never use literal dates in culture specific formats. You might [read this (and other answers there)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39504506/5089204)
- Compare data always in the type needed. You are converting dates to string just to compare them *alphanumerically*?
- in `convert(varchar,'12/09/2016',103)` you are using `varchar` without a length... [One more *bad habit to kick*](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Try to change your `WHERE` clause to this (all datetimes on 12th of September, but not on 13th)

```
WHERE a.U_datetime >= {d'2016-09-12'} AND a.U_datetime<{d'2016-09-13'}
```

or this (all datetimes of 12th and of 13th September)

```
WHERE a.U_datetime >= {d'2016-09-12'} AND a.U_datetime<{d'2016-09-14'}
```

Comment: which 1 should I use, first one or second one.. I am confused

Comment: @nad Sorry, there was a `convert` to much... See my update

Comment: what's `d` here ??

Comment: @nad. This is `ODBC`-format. Find details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i/39504506#39504506) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190234(v=sql.90).aspx).

Comment: superb explanation on the links. Thanks , will rectify and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert to DATETIME

```
...
BETWEEN convert(datetime,'12/09/2016',103)
  AND convert(datetime,'13/09/2016',103)
```

currently the query just leaves BETWEEN arguments as VARCHAR and then the server needs to compare them with `convert(datetime,a.U_datetime,103)`. At that moment they are converted to DATETIME with no format specified.

Comment: @Shnugo It's just a matter of remembering BETWEEN is inclusive (>= ,<=) for dates, integers, whatever type.

Comment: Not really... The very last moments before and after midnight can be a problem... taking `BETWEEN {d'2016-09-17'} AND {d'2016-09-18'}` will **inlcude** a record of exactly midnight + tiny time of the **next** day, while `BETWEEN {d'2016-09-17'} AND {ts'2016-09-17 23:59:59'}` could miss records of the very last second (even if specified with milliseconds...). Admitably a very small problem, but not necessary...