# --SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, gradd19, 105) FROM gradeddetails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

rom_date column is datetime format-----temptable1stockdetails.

gradd19 column is varchar format------gradeddetails

to insert gradd19 value to from_date. but error came.plase tell.

### EDIT the code taken from OP's comment:

```
insert into TempTable1STOCKDETAILS (PRODUCT_NO,PRODUCT_NAME,AC_NO,FROM_DATE,QTY_IN,B_F) 
SELECT a.PRODUCT_NO PRODUCT_NO
      ,P.PRODUCT_NAME PRODUCT_NAME
      ,a.CATEGORY ProductGroup
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), gradd19, 105) as ExpiryDate
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QTY_IN),0) FROM GradedDETAILS WHERE CATEGORY=a.CATEGORY AND PRODUCT_NO=A.PRODUCT_NO 
                                                          AND STOCK_JR IN ('IN','GR','TR','SA','SR','OG','PO','LT') 
                                                          AND STOCK_DATE BETWEEN '2016-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-09-28 00:00:00')
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QTY_IN),0) FROM GradedDETAILS WHERE STOCK_DATE < '2016-09-01 00:00:00' 
                                                          AND PRODUCT_NO=A.PRODUCT_NO AND CATEGORY=a.CATEGORY ) 
FROM GradedDETAILS A 
inner join PRODUCT P on A.PRODUCT_NO=P.PRODUCT_NO 
WHERE a.STOCK_JR IN('IN','GR','TR','SA','SR','OG','PO','LT') 
GROUP BY a.PRODUCT_NO,P.PRODUCT_NAME ,a.CATEGORY,a.Gradd19
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why date is not taking 13/09/2016](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718482/why-date-is-not-taking-13-09-2016)

Comment: We had quite the [same issue some minutes before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39718482/5089204)... Try to do some research first...

Comment: And please don't paste your code as pictures.

Comment: You need to specify size of `VARCHAR` - change it to `VARCHAR(some_size)`.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: insert into TempTable1STOCKDETAILS (PRODUCT_NO,PRODUCT_NAME,AC_NO,FROM_DATE,QTY_IN,B_F)  
SELECT  a.PRODUCT_NO PRODUCT_NO, P.PRODUCT_NAME PRODUCT_NAME,a.CATEGORY ProductGroup, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), gradd19, 105) as  ExpiryDate,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QTY_IN),0)   FROM GradedDETAILS
 WHERE CATEGORY=a.CATEGORY  AND PRODUCT_NO=A.PRODUCT_NO AND STOCK_JR IN
 ('IN','GR','TR','SA','SR','OG','PO','LT')  AND STOCK_DATE  BETWEEN   
 '2016-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-09-28 00:00:00'), (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QTY_IN),0) 
 FROM GradedDETAILS WHERE  STOCK_DATE  <  '2016-09-01 00:00:00' AND

Comment: PRODUCT_NO=A.PRODUCT_NO AND CATEGORY=a.CATEGORY  )   FROM GradedDETAILS A inner join 
 PRODUCT P on A.PRODUCT_NO=P.PRODUCT_NO WHERE   a.STOCK_JR IN('IN','GR','TR','SA','SR','OG','PO','LT')
  GROUP BY a.PRODUCT_NO,P.PRODUCT_NAME ,a.CATEGORY,a.Gradd19

Comment: the above two coments code is full cod...please merge the code...and tell me that error

Comment: @srinivas, did you read the linked question? You are repeating quite the same errors we saw there...

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you an error because `varchar` can't store your converted date format which results in an out-of range error.

```
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), gradd19, 105) FROM gradeddetails
```

Convert it to `VARCHAR(10)` instead of `VARCHAR`

Comment: execute the your query change only data range.... but same error is came...

Comment: @srinivas Can you add the code and error instead of adding image?

Comment: sorry dont have any image upload button.....                                    insert into TempTable1STOCKDETAILS (PRODUCT_NO,PRODUCT_NAME,AC_NO,FROM_DATE,QTY_IN,B_F)  
SELECT  a.PRODUCT_NO PRODUCT_NO, P.PRODUCT_NAME PRODUCT_NAME,a.CATEGORY ProductGroup, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), gradd19, 105) as  ExpiryDate,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QTY_IN),0)   FROM GradedDETAILS
 WHERE CATEGORY=a.CATEGORY  AND PRODUCT_NO=A.PRODUCT_NO AND STOCK_JR I

Comment: @srinivas Is this the full query?

Comment: NO...just first three lines sample code...full code is in above imgae