# SQL converting date and/or time from character string error

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am pretty new to SQL. 
I am trying to show in a select since when the customer is in the database but i am getting the error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Here is the code which i try to show the date.

```
SELECT Naam + ' is klant sinds ' + [Klant sinds] FROM tblKlant
```

`[Klant sinds]` is a datetime type.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i)

Comment: cast it to varchar like: `SELECT Naam + ' is klant sinds ' + CAST([Klant sinds] as nvarchar(50)) FROM tblKlant` but you may not get it into the desired format

Comment: Why are you formatting the text of your select list in a sql query. Thats what UI code is for. Select your 2 fields and format in your favourite UI coding platform.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT Naam + ' is klant sinds ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Klant sinds],101) FROM tblKlant`

101=US date/time format
[For a complete list of possible date/time formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `SELECT CAST(Naam as varchar) + ' is klant sinds ' + CAST([Klant sinds] as varchar) FROM tblKlant`

I have casted Naam as varchar to ensure everything is in varchar/string type

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server 2012 you can use `CONCAT` to concatinate all sorts of values together, without having to worry about casting or `NULL` values:

```
DECLARE @v_naam           NVARCHAR(100); SET @v_naam = N'Mic Mac Jampudding';
DECLARE @v_date           DATETIME;      SET @v_date = GETDATE();
DECLARE @v_somenullvalue  NVARCHAR(10);  SET @v_somenullvalue = NULL;
DECLARE @v_aninteger      SMALLINT;      SET @v_aninteger = 5;

SELECT CONCAT(@v_naam, ' is klant sinds ', @v_date, '. Some null value: ', @v_somenullvalue, ' and a lovely int: ', @v_aninteger);
```

Output:

```
Mic Mac Jampudding is klant sinds May 17 2017 11:27AM. Some null value:  and a lovely int: 5
```

If you just want the date without having the time part on your `DATETIME` you can use the following:

```
CAST(@v_date AS DATE)
```