# Error while inserting date from textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am new to C#, and learning. I have a SQL Server database where I have table `record` that has a column `dob` of data type `date`. I am trying to insert into `dob` from my textbox which has a value of `19-08-17` with the following code

```
datebox.Text = "19-08-17";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
string query= "insert into record (dob) values(@db)";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@db", datebox.Text);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Self-explanatory! Since your column type in the database is date, Convert `datebox.Text` to date format while setting the parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i)

Comment: Error is explaining it self : Typecast error, try this:
DateTime.Parse(datebox.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a variable to a DateTime column as a parameter, you need to convert the text to a `DateTime` variable before passing it:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].Connect    ionString);

// Convert the textbox text to a DateTime variable
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(datebox.Text, "dd-MM-yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
string query= "insert into record (dob) values(@db)";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@db", myDate);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: wow  its working fine now. i want to ask one more thing from you

Comment: yes am waiting system saying wait 5 minutes to accept answer,

Comment: No problem, what do you want to ask?

Comment: i want to be professional programmer like others and you, how i can ? am good learner if i have good guideline

Comment: @rahulyadav It's just a matter of a lot of practice and writing as much code as you can. First, take a good C# tutorial online, there are so many of them. Then, try writing as many programs and websites as you can. It will come with time, with experience. Nobody is born being a good programmer. Also, read many posts as possible on this site, and even try answering some questions yourself, even if you are not sure.

Comment: ok thanks but am confused which language should i learn fully, some time learn php, some tim android development and now am learning asp.net with c#. inshort have no one path

Comment: @rahulyadav That's not good. You have to stick with 1 programming language until you feel like you controls it completely. I suggest you stick with ASP.NET and C#, while using Javascript on the client side. This will provide you an entire world of capabilities.