# How to convert custom string to Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to convert `yyyyMMddhh` (`2017092018`) string to `Date` in SQL Server 2012?

Is it possible to do without using T-SQL to put the sentence into the `INSERT` clause?

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table](SomeColumn) 
VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017092018', 'yyyyMMddhh'));
```

Comment: `Is it possible to do without using T-SQL to put the sentence into the INSERT clause?` - I'm not sure what you're asking here...

Comment: Create a function in sql with string parameter and return Date. You can also make your function running with different custom date formats.

Comment: Is the string always in that exact format?  Always the same number of characters?

Comment: Another question after your edit...  you specifically say `DATE` twice in your question, but your example says `DATETIME`.  What are you looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i)

Comment: Yes, it's always in the same format.

Comment: Just saying.  Tanner's solution should really be the accepted answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(50)='2017092018'

Select convert(datetime,left(@S,8)) + convert(datetime,right(@S,2)+':00')
```

**Returns**

```
2017-09-20 18:00:00.000
```

If 2012+, I would suggest try_convert() just in case you have some unexpected values.

Comment: +1 from me. I didn't want to post a contradictory answer but I came up with a different approach. dateadd(hour, convert(int, right(@s, 2)), left(@s, 8))

Comment: @SeanLange Post it!  That is the beauty of SO...  Options

Comment: Thanks, but as I expected there is no conversion string to Date by mask =(

Comment: Old post, but still cant resist to wonder , whey sqlserver doesn't support using a standard syntax ,using format string like `cast('1-1-2021', 'd-m-yyyy')`. Or is it there?

Comment: @sjd Seems like a missed opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate approach using [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(25) = '2017092018';

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(@val, 9, 0, ' ') + ':00')
```

This adds a space before the hour, then adds `:00` for the minute value.

Comment: Already +1  ... Should be the accepted answer  Got stuck on my initial thought.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @d NVARCHAR(10)='2017092018';

SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(LEFT(@d,4),SUBSTRING(@d,5,2),SUBSTRING(@d,7,2),RIGHT(@d,2),0,0,0 ) ;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/JBDH48508)**

EDIT:

Another option:

```
DECLARE @S varchar(10)='2017092018'
SELECT CAST(LEFT(@s, 8) AS DATETIME) + RIGHT(@s,2)/24.0;
```

**[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/DDBN35692)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another approach to this. It is similar to what John Cappelletti posted.

```
Declare @S varchar(50)='2017092018'

Select dateadd(hour, convert(int, right(@s, 2)), left(@s, 8))
```

Comment: `Select CAST(left(@s, 8) AS DATETIME) + RIGHT(@s,2)/24.0;`