# How to convert MM/YYYY/DD format string to DATE in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, date-conversion

I have a column for which I need to convert the data to DATE format. I receive below error whenever I encounter the data 'MM/YYYY/DD' format, but it works fine for other formats.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Sample data:

```
SELECT CAST('05/2020/29' AS DATE);
```

`SELECT ISDATE('05/2020/29')` returns `1` but `CAST` or `CONVERT` functions fail.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of [How to convert custom string to Date in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324500/how-to-convert-custom-string-to-date-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a weird format. I would recommend `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(
    substring(mycol, 4, 4), 
    left(mycol, 2), 
    right(mycol, 2)
) mydate
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de9397cfa9ceac6fb8194bbf097ec3f7)**:

```
with mytable as (select '05/2020/29' mycol)
select datefromparts(substring(mycol, 4, 4), left(mycol, 2), right(mycol, 2)) mydate
from mytable
```

```
| mydate     |
| :--------- |
| 2020-05-29 |
```

Answer (score 3):

I must admit, the format `MM/yyyy/dd` is a rather odd choice of format for a date. The reason, problem, however, is that you're storing date (and time) data in a `varchar`.

To do this, however, I could rearrange the data into an ISO format (`yyyyMMdd`) and then `CONVERT`:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(YourString,4,4),LEFT(YourString,2),RIGHT(YourString,2)),112)
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

I use `TRY_CONVERT` here as experience has proved countless times that those that store date (and time) data as a `varchar` in a database also end up with bad data (like `'13/2020/11'` for your style). This means that the conversion won't fail when these bad rows are met and `NULL` is returned instead.

Ideally, though, you should be fixing your column and changing the data type. We can actually do this using a similar solution to the above. Firstly by changing the value to the ISO format in the column, but as a `varchar`, and testing the conversion, and then altering the data type:

```sql
UPDATE YT
SET YT.YourString = CONVERT(varchar(8),V.YourDate,112)
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(date,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(YourString,4,4),LEFT(YourString,2),RIGHT(YourString,2)),112)))V(YourDate);

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourString date NULL;
```

Side note as well, `ISDATE` is a terrible function, like it's "sibling" `ISNUMERIC`. Both functions return false positives and negatives, and should be avoided. `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST` are better alternatives by far.

As a quick example, notice the following values returned for the below:

```sql
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH; --American, not English...

SELECT ISDATE(20200928); --Returns 1
SELECT ISDATE(17); -Returns 0
SELECT ISDATE('09/2020/28'); --Returns 1
```

And now, let's try some conversions:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,20200928); --ISDATE returned 1
```

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,17); --ISDATE returned 0
```

Success, returns the `datetime` `1900-01-18T00:00:00.000`.

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0),'09/2020/28'); --ISDATE returned 1
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 2):

You can try it specifying first the dateformat:

```
SET DATEFORMAT MYD;
SELECT CAST('05/2020/29' AS DATE);
```