# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string: trx_date

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm getting the error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

when I execute the query below in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    payment_date, 
    CONVERT(varchar, CAST(amount AS money), 1) amount, 
    trx_date 
FROM vi_mpesa_payments2
WHERE bulk_center = 'LONDON'
AND (cast(convert(date,[trx_date],3) as varchar(30)) = '2018-07-23')
```

The value of `trx_date` is '23/07/2018' of type varchar, which I'm converting to date and changing the date format then casting it to varchar in order to do the comparison. This should work but it doesn't, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i)

Comment: bad idea to store date in `varchar` data type. Should use `date` or `datetime`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick: choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
payment_date, 
CONVERT(varchar, CAST(amount AS money), 1) amount, 
trx_date 
FROM vi_mpesa_payments2
WHERE bulk_center = 'LONDON'
AND 
(convert(datetime, [trx_date], 103) = cast('2018-07-23' as date))
```

Answer (score 1):

to simply resolve your error, just change style to `103`. Do note that style `3` is `DD/MM/YY` without the century

If the `trx_date` is varchar, why not just simply use compare directly without converting

```
AND [trx_date] = '23/07/2018'
```

Anyway, you should store date in `date` or `datetime` data type.

Comment: Style 103 gives the same error unfortunately. Tried many styles but none work

Comment: probably you have some rows that the format is not `DD/MM/YYYY`. Try verify your data. Or simply use string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try_convert()` function & i would suggest to identity your `varchar` date format using :

```
select *
from vi_mpesa_payments2
where try_convert(date, trx_date, 103) is null;
```

Then you can use :

```
SELECT DISTINCT payment_date, CONVERT(varchar, CAST(amount AS money), 1) amount, 
       o_trx_date AS trx_date
FROM vi_mpesa_payments2 CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES try_convert(date, trx_date, 103)
     ) t (o_trx_date)
WHERE bulk_center = 'LONDON' AND
      o_trx_date = '2018-07-23';
```