# Export date from Excel to SQL Server using ADODB

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, type-conversion

I got errors converting an Excel date to SQL Server.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

```
rs.open "Table", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
rs.addNew
rs("DateColumn") = rng.Value
```

I solved the problem adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14119145)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using this code:

```
If rng.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" Then
    rs("DateColumn") = CLng(Format(rng.Value, "yyyymmdd"))
End If
```

Comment: So the issue was in database column setup then? Also, might be worth accepting your answer just to close the question

Comment: @Zac The date column is defined as a "date".