# Comversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

i made a button that would input the current date and time into a database in sql

```
Dim curDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim regDate As String = curDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
qr = "Insert into sales (SaleDate) Values ('" & regDate & "')
```

it worked on another button that's on another form but i got this error on a diff button that's on a diff form

i tried doing this

```
qr = "Insert into sales (SaleDate) Values ('" & DateTime.Now & "')
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Don't convert the `Date` to a `String`.  Use the `Date`.  Learn how to use parameters in ADO.NET code.  You should not be converting anything to a `String` unless you need to and you never need to with ADO.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This was a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i) in a previous post.

The possible reason is that the date is involved, that is, the data you use to insert the data ***DateTime.Now ()*** is not the required format. It is Merely because you are trying to store wrong data that is not acceptable to the system.
Try using **ISO-8601** date format, which is the best option for SQL Sever.

You can see this document for [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

your button

```
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into sales (Date,Time) values (@Date,@Time)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM,yyyy"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"))
```

Comment: the date doesn't generate from the textbox, it automatically inputs into the database

Comment: i already did, the current date and time would be stored in SaleDate that has a datatype of datetime

Comment: what you need explain in details

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @gkan12 Sending anydesk is not the Stack Overflow way of doing things. Private communication is of no value to future readers.

Comment: @gkan12 Why did you change a single field `SalesDate` into two fields? You have also arbitrarily changed the format of the date portion.

Answer (score 0):

Database objects need to be closed and disposed. Using...End Using blocks take care of this for you even if there is an error.

I had to guess what kind of database you are using. If it is not Sql Server then you need to change the types of the database objects. For example, for Access it would be `OleDbConnection` etc..

If `SalesDate` is not a `DateTime` datatype in the database, it should be.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert into sales (SaleDate) Values (@regDate);", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@regDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```