# SQL Query in Azure Dataflow does not work when using parameter value in where clause

Tags: sql, azure, parameters, lookup

I use a Azure Datafactory Pipeline.
[image]

Within that pipeline i use 2 activities:

1. Lookup to get a date value
   This is the output:

   "firstRow": {
   "Date": "2022-10-26T00:00:00Z"
2. A dataflow which is getting the date from the lookup in 1 which is used in the source options SQL query in the where clause:

[image]

This is the query:

```
"SELECT ProductID ,ProductName ,SupplierID,CategoryID ,QuantityPerUnit ,UnitPrice ,UnitsInStock,UnitsOnOrder,ReorderLevel,Discontinued,LastModifiedDate FROM Noordwind.Products where LastModifiedDate >= '{$DS_LastPipeLineRunDate}'"
```

When i fill the parameter by hand with for example '2022-10-26' then it works great, but when i let the parameter get's its value from the Lookup in step 1 the dataflow fails
Error message:

```
{"message":"Job failed due to reason: Converting to a date or time failed due to an invalid character. Details:null","failureType":"UserError","target":"Products","errorCode":"DF-Executor-Conversion"}
```

This is the parameter in the pipeline view, but clicked on the dataflow:
[image]

I have tried casting the date al kind of things but not the right thing.
Can you help me.

UPDATE:
After a question from Rakesh:
This is the activity parameter
@activity('LookupLastPipelineRunDate').output.firstRow

Comment: Is the pipeline expression `@activity('lookup').output.firstRow.Date`? could you please add that one also for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and got the below results.

My source sample data from SQL database.

[image]

For demo, I have used set variable for the date and given a sample date like below.

[image]

Created a string parameter and given this variable value to it.

[image]

In your case pass the lookup firstrow output date.

I have used below dataflow expression in the query of dataflow source and got the desired result.

```
concat('select * from dbo.table1 where d1 >=','\'',$date_value,'\'')
```

[image]

**Result in a target SQL table.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but your idea dit not work. Maybe i'm doing something wrong. Let me explain in my answer so i can use pictures to explain

Answer (score 0):

I have created an activity set variable:

[image]

The first pipeline still returns the right date.
I even converted it just to be sure to datetime.

[image]

I can create a variable with type string.
[image]
Code:
@activity('LookupLastPipelineRunDate').output.firstRow

Regardless of the activity set variable that fails, it looks like the date enters nicely as an input in the Set variable activity

[image]

And still a get an error:
[image]

When i read this error message, it says that you can't put a date in a string variable. But i can only choose string, boolean and array, so there is no better option for this.

I also reviewd this website.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i)

There for i have altered the table which contains the source data which i use in the dataflow.
I Deleted the column LastModifiedDate because it has datatype datetime.
Now i created the same column with datatype datetime2
I did this because i read that datetime2 has less problems with conversions.

[image]