# I'm having a convert issue from varchar to date data type

Tags: date, t-sql, type-conversion

I have a CTE table and I'm having this problem below

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

when I query piece of that particular code it's not working with CAST function, when I try `TRY_CAST` it's working, but it's not working in the main CTE select statement

I query varchar field and isdate function side by side, all of them returns 0
I checked all of them one by one and for example this one below it looks date data type to me 2019-06-01 00:00:00.0000000

I haven't seen any funky records like 019-06-01, I can't understand why I can't use it

Any ideas, solutions?

Comment: Why are you storing date (and time) data as a `varchar` in the first place? If you need to find what values are bad, however, then query your column with the following `WHERE`: `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date,YourColumn) IS NULL AND YourColumn IS NOT NULL;` This will tell you what dates are bad. Then you'll need to take the time to *fix* that data.

Comment: Please fellow the link below for this issue its already answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i

Comment: @ThomA because we have different records (integer,date,string) for different categories under one field that has to be kept in varchar. I tried your where clause and there was no records return. I even tried this CAST(REPLACE(LEFT(varchar_field,10),'-','') AS DATE) and it didn't work

Comment: @FazalQayyum thank you, these records will be used in react application and javascript couldn't convert with T delimeter and that's why records are kept datetime2 without T delimeter and that's causing issue in ssms now.

Comment: Sounds like you have a design flaw then, @brickanalyst .

Comment: *"we have different records (integer,date,string) for different categories under one field that has to be kept in varchar. I tried your where clause and there was no records return"* these 2 statements conflict. One cannot be true if the other is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while CAST function is not working and TRY_CAST is working, I added case when condition to return if values can be casted to date data type, else NULL

it's working.

ps: all records in the filtered select statement returns values 1 for ISDATE()
I don't even know why CAST is not working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).